# ASP Site Master page and linked PHP Footer

Tags: php, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

Can I include an external PHP footer document in an ASP.NET Web Forms Site Master?

The idea is, we have a CMS site and an Application Site, both on the same domain. The CMS Admin will update the footer quit often (which is called footer.php), WordPress CMS, and all I want to do is link in my Site Master  section to that footer.php file? Don't know if that will be possible at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the response text to from the php page to the asp page it should work, just make sure that the PHP file is parsed first (eg. running on a server).

Comment: Great stuff. You gave me an idea to try this and seems to do the trick!
<% Response.WriteFile("footer.php"); %>

Comment: Yes! Well it was something like that i ment, sorry for my obscure description of the solution.